# How to create a button in live activity?How can not allow open app when click this button?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

How to create a button in live activity?How can not allow open app when click this button?[image]

Comment: This is now possible in iOS 17: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77190001/1759443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t. Third-party Live Activities cannot have any interactivity.

You can add a Link and style it like a button, but tapppng the link will *always* open your app.

EDIT: The above is true for iOS 16 but not iOS 17. Please see Kyle's answer for iOS 17+.

Answer (score 2):

#### September 2023 Update

Now you can in iOS 17! [Full documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/adding-interactivity-to-widgets-and-live-activities).

> Starting with iOS 17, iPadOS 17, or macOS 14, widgets and Live Activities can include buttons and toggles to offer specific app functionality without launching the app
>
> For example, a Reminders widget allows people to mark a task as completed with a toggle. On a locked device, buttons and toggles are inactive and the system doesn’t perform actions unless a person authenticates and unlocks their device.

#### Add the functionality as an intent

1. For a widget, create a new structure that adopts the `AppIntent` protocol and add it to your app target. For a Live Activity interactive, adopt the `LiveActivityIntent` protocol
2. Implement the protocol’s requirements.
3. Define input parameters that your action needs using the `@Parameter` property wrapper (must conform to `AppEntity`)
4. In the protocol’s required `perform()` function, add code for the action you want to make available to the widget.

Example:

```swift
@available(iOS 16.0, macOS 13.0, watchOS 9.0, tvOS 16.0, *)
struct SuperCharge: LiveActivityIntent {
    
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Emoji Ranger SuperCharger"
    static var description = IntentDescription("All heroes get instant 100% health.")
    
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        EmojiRanger.superchargeHeros()
        return .result()
    }
}
```

Notes

- The `perform()` function is asynchronous.
- When you return from the perform() function, the system reloads the widget’s timeline using its timeline provider.
- The perform() function is marked as throws.

#### Add the button

```swift
struct EmojiRangerWidgetEntryView: View {
    var entry: SimpleEntry
    
    @Environment(\.widgetFamily) var family
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        switch family {
        
        // Code for other widget sizes.
           
        case .systemLarge:
            if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Button(intent: SuperCharge()) {
                        Image(systemName: "bolt.fill")
                    }
                }
                .tint(.white)
                .padding()
            }
            // ...rest of view
       }
    }
}
```